# XSLT to HTML navbar Menu

Tags: html, xslt

I wanted to create a navbar menu like that :

```
<table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td id="navBar" width="15%">
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><b id="menu">Menu</b></li>
                                <!-- menu here -->
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </td>
                    <td width="85%">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="frontmatter"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

And i have an XML file with that Structure :

```
<body>
     <chapter id="...1">
                 <title>...</title>
                 <section id="...1">
                               <title>...</title>
                               <subsection id="...1">
                                                <title>...</title>
                                                <subsubsection id="...1">
                 <section id="...2">
                    .
                    .
     <chapter id="...2">
      .
      .
```

Basically, i can have a lot of `chapter` each `chapter` have a `title`.

`section`can have also multiple `section` with `title` on each `section` and, `subsection` and `subsubsection`does have the same way with the title and the multiplicity as the `section`.

My question is: How could i get the title and put on my navbar as an `<a href ...>` when the order is very important ? (With the right number also)
For example :

```
1. title (referencing to chapter 1) 
1.1 title of section (referecing for chapter 1 section 1)
etc etc
```

I don't know how i could do that with XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate numbering using the [`<xsl:number>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#format-number) element. Use the `count` attribute to include the elements you want to count, and the `level="multiple"` to count them in multiple nesting levels. The `format` allows you to increment arabic digits, roman digits, etc.

By including:

```
<xsl:number format="1. " level="multiple" count="chapter | section | subsection | subsubsection"/>
```

before the `<value-of>` that prints each `title`, you can generate multi-section numbering.

Here is a stylesheet. It doesn't use the data in your `id` attributes (but you can, of course) but generates a URI fragment using the section numbering with the form `#sec1.1.1`. Each item is generated in a named template. The order is controlled by each template that calls the nested sections:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td id="navBar" width="15%">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><b id="menu">Menu</b></li>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="body/chapter"/>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </td>
                <td width="85%">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="frontmatter"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="chapter">
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-item"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-item"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="subsection"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="subsection">
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-item"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="subsubsection"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="subsubsection">
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-item"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="generate-item">
        <li><a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:text>#sec</xsl:text>
                <xsl:number format="1" level="multiple" count="chapter | section | subsection | subsubsection"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:number format="1. " level="multiple" count="chapter | section | subsection | subsubsection"/><xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </a></li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using this input:

```
<body>
    <chapter id="c1">
        <title>Title of chapter 1</title>
        <section id="c1s1">
            <title>Title of Section</title>
            <subsection id="s1s1">
                <title>Title of SubSection</title>
                <subsubsection id="s1s1s1">
                    <title>Title of SubSubSection</title>
                </subsubsection>
            </subsection>
        </section>
        <section id="c1s2">
            <title>Title of Section</title>
            <section id="c1s2s1">
                <title>Title of SubSection</title>
                <subsection id="c1s2s1s1">
                    <title>Title of SubSubSection</title>
                </subsection>
            </section>
        </section>
    </chapter>
    <chapter id="c2">
        <title>Title of Chapter 2</title>
        <section id="c2s1">
            <title>Title of Section</title>
            <subsection id="c2s1s1">
                <title>Title of SubSection</title>
                <subsubsection id="c2s1s1s1">
                    <title>Title of SubSubSection</title>
                </subsubsection>
            </subsection>
        </section>
        <section id="c2s2">
            <title>Title of Section</title>
            <section id="c2s2s1">
                <title>Title of SubSection</title>
                <subsection id="c2s2s1s1">
                    <title>Title of SubSubSection</title>
                </subsection>
            </section>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</body>
```

You will have this result:

```
<table width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td id="navBar" width="15%">
         <nav>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <b id="menu">Menu</b>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#sec1">1. Title of chapter 1</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#sec1.1">1.1. Title of Section</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#sec1.1.1">1.1.1. Title of SubSection</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#sec1.1.1.1">1.1.1.1. Title of SubSubSection</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#sec1.2">1.2. Title of Section</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#sec2">2. Title of Chapter 2</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#sec2.1">2.1. Title of Section</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#sec2.1.1">2.1.1. Title of SubSection</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#sec2.1.1.1">2.1.1.1. Title of SubSubSection</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#sec2.2">2.2. Title of Section</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </td>
      <td width="85%"/>
   </tr>
</table>
```

You can try it out in this **[XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHSW/2)**

Comment: Seems working ! But i have an other question which is : If i wanna also put that information on a body and to make anchors will it be possible ?

Comment: Yes. You would need a new template extracting data perhaps from the same elements. You can use the `mode` attribute to distinguish the two operations, since you might have templates matching the same source elements. Perhaps `mode="toc"` and `mode="body"`.

Comment: i think i made it , by passing a parameters true or false ! :) Thank you Helder !

Comment: Is it better doing with the mode or parameters ?

Comment: Use mode if you need to (when you have two templates that match the same expressions), or if it will make the code clearer.

Comment: I'm using parameters and doing a `choose statement`, because i need to write different things when `chapter`is called. So i don't think that `mode`will do that

Comment: It's a different style of programming. It's *usually* more efficient to select using templates, `mode` and XPath instead of `choose`, `if` or `for-each`.

Comment: And how could i choose the different mode in `<xsl:template match=chapter` ?

Comment: You can use the mode attribute in apply-templates.

Comment: you mean like this example right ? http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/OutputOverview/xslt_apply-templates_mode_frame.html